# Using different storyboards for different screen sizes on load? xcode Swift

Tags: swift, storyboard, screen-size

I just want to load a specific storyboard when a certain iPhone size loads the app.
I'm really struggling to get the desired out come using auto layout.

I've done a lot of searching and found code someone shared 4 years ago and tried using it but I got a lot of errors, could someone with more knowledge have a look at the code and see if it needs updating please?

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: 
    AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

var bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
var screenHeight: NSNumber = bounds.size.height
var deviceFamily: String

var mainView: UIStoryboard!
mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "iphone35Storyboard", bundle: nil)
let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iphone35") as UIViewController
self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller

if screenHeight == 480  {
    deviceFamily = "iPhoneOriginal"
    // Load Storyboard with name: iPhone4
    var mainView: UIStoryboard!
    mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iphone4") as UIViewController
    self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller

} else {

    var mainView: UIStoryboard!
    mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "IpadStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ipad") as UIViewController
    self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller

    if screenHeight == 920 {
        deviceFamily = "Pad"
        // Load Storyboard with name: ipad
        var mainView: UIStoryboard!
        mainView = UIStoryboard(name: "IpadStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ipad") as UIViewController
        self.window!.rootViewController = viewcontroller
    }
    }
    }
```

Errors experienced -

Instance method 'application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' of protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'

'instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier' has been renamed to 'instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)'

Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIScreen'

Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to specified type 'NSNumber'

Comment: Don’t use any of that code, throw it away and learn auto layout. If you’re struggling with it, post a question. It’s a very straightforward API and can be learned very quickly.

Comment: Thanks but I really just need to get the above code working if possible.

Comment: Auto layout and the storyboard were built to do exactly what your question is asking to do. Apple does not want you to do it your way. Nobody will hire you as a programmer if they see you do it this way. Learn it the right way, it's very simple. If you can't get auto layout or the storyboard working, post a question here and we'll be very happy to answer it. But the code above is a complete non-starter IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift is still evolving and with every version of Swift there are many changes in the syntax. All those errors that you are getting are because that 4 years old code was meant for some older versions of swift. In Swift 4, you can use

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let deviceIdiom = UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceIdiom

        if deviceIdiom == .pad {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourFirstStoryboard", bundle: nil)
            if let firstVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstVC_Identifier") as? FirstVC {
                self.window?.rootViewController = firstVC
            }

        } else if deviceIdiom == .phone {

            if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone) && (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height < 568.0) {

                /* "< 568" = iphone 4 or less */
                /* Similarly you can use other "else if" conditions with.. */
                /* "== 568" = iphone 5 and 5c */
                /* "== 667" = iphone 6,7 or 8 */
                /* "== 736" = iphone 6P,7P or 8 */
                /* "== 812" = iphone X, XR or XS */
                /* "== 896" = iphone X, XR or XS */

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourSecondStoryboard", bundle: nil)
                if let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC_Identifier") as? SecondVC {
                    self.window?.rootViewController = secondVC
                }

            }
        }

        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. I am however still getting errors with the above code - (Use of undeclared type 'FirstVC') where or how am I supposed to use FirstVC?

Comment: FirstVC is just a name I used (I meant your first view controller), just like "SecondVC", "YourFirstStoryboard" and "YourSecondStoryboard". You can give your view controller's name there. I see, you have not used any sub classes for your view controller. Okay, then you can use "let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iphone4") as UIViewController"

Comment: Thanks but I'm now stuck on where to place you new code `let viewcontroller : UIViewController = mainView.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("iphone4") as UIViewController` When I replace the sections I think I should I still get errors (Use of unresolved identifier 'mainView') so sorry for my lack of knowledge and I really appreciate that help. Also I dont need to declare my device as Im only running it on iPhone...if that helps?

Comment: and a - Thread 1: signal SIGABRT - on the class AppDelegate: UIResponder line

Comment: you can use storyboard instead of mainView then. Both storyboard and mainView are just random names i've given. You can use any name for that